# TextToSpeech in android handler

Tags: android, text-to-speech

In my app i am displaying images 1 after other for 1 second.In that when first image comes i want use there texttospeech method to describe that image.i tried that.but null pointer exception is coming.here is the code -

```
public class Shapes extends Activity {


    private TextToSpeech mTts;
     int flag=0;
     ImageView iv;
     int myData=1;
     Handler handler = new Handler();
     static int v[]={R.drawable.roundd,R.drawable.rectangle,R.drawable.bluesquare};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.shapes);
         iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
             handler.postDelayed(changeImage, 2000);
    }

     Runnable changeImage = new Runnable(){

         @Override
         public void run(){
             if(flag>2)
                handler.removeCallbacks(changeImage);
             else{
                 mTts.speak("hii", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                iv.setImageResource(v[flag++]);

              Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
                checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
                startActivityForResult(checkIntent,myData);   
             }
         }

     };

     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == myData) {
                if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                    // success, create the TTS instance
                    mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, (OnInitListener) this);
                }

                else {
                    // missing data, install it
                    Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                    installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                    startActivity(installIntent);
                }
            }

        }

    public void onInit(int status) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
             // Toast.makeText(Abcd.this, "Text-To-Speech engine is initialized", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
        else if (status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error occurred while initializing Text-To-Speech engine", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

    }
```

logcat info-

```
11-29 10:21:07.118: E/AndroidRuntime(461): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-29 10:21:07.118: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at com.my.KidsEasyLearning.Shapes$1.run(Shapes.java:37)
11-29 10:21:07.118: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-29 10:21:07.118: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-29 10:21:07.118: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-29 10:21:07.118: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-29 10:21:07.118: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 10:21:07.118: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-29 10:21:07.118: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-29 10:21:07.118: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-29 10:21:07.118: E/AndroidRuntime(461):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-29 10:21:09.899: I/Process(461): Sending signal. PID: 461 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What's the 37th line of Shapes.java?

Comment: it was mTts.speak("hii", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null); but after making changes that you told below its working..now it show only first image.not showing other

Comment: Did you try debugging it? I think mTts is null at that time

Comment: mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, (OnInitListener) this); should be called before mTts.speak("hii", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);

Comment: Did you debug the code? What is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement TextToSpeech in your adtivity class.

And declare variable as

```
mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
```

These were visible mistakes. Refer to [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/) tutorial for guidance

Comment: actually its working..but only 1st image is displaying..and then it stops

Answer (score 1):

The startup process for TextToSpeech can be a little trick. I suggest using the build in code from this library

https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/SpeechRecognizingAndSpeakingActivity.java